# raise "pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (3221225477, '')"

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I got the following error when I tried to find out the Chinese words in a picture by python: (By the way, I had already had "chi_sim.traineddata" training file in tessdata directory and got a successful try to find out English sentences in a picture, so this error really confused me.)

```
*C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe E:/PKU1.3/python_math/set_for_recognition.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/PKU1.3/python_math/set_for_recognition.py", line 5, in <module>
    text=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('climb_high.jpeg'),lang='chi_sim')
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 295, in image_to_string
    return run_and_get_output(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 203, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 179, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(status_code, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (3221225477, '')*
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is `TRAINEDDATA` that raised.

I used to develop the OCR project with TESSERACT on windows 7.

Now, I change to windows 10. I get this problem.

but, I found this issue is related to your `TRAINEDDATA`,

If I use TRAINEDDATA that I have trained on windows 7, then it fine without any error message.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code :

```
import pytesseract

from PIL import Image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata"'

img = Image.open('images\Capture2.JPG')

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=tessdata_dir_config)

print(text)
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer but it'd be better if you explained a little bit about what this code does and why you'd choose it instead of one of the established answers?

Answer (score 0):

Actually since the error code 3221225477 --> 0xC0000005 : ACCESS_VIOLATION means Tesseract has crashed (from [here](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/issues/105)), change a version of Tesseract may help you.

In 4.00 (beta) and 3.02 this problem is occurred, 3.05 is fine (I use Windows 7).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because my UZN file extended beyond the image area.  I patched [pytesseract.py](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/pytesseract.py#L182) (`print(' '.join(cmd_args))` in `run_tesseract()`) which was throwing an assertion error.

Comment: your patched `pytesseract.py` link is not working

Comment: maybe this will help  https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/tree/master/pytesseract  LINE 182