# pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (3221225477, '')* on Windows Server

Tags: python, windows, tesseract, windows-server-2012, python-tesseract

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 75, in <module>
    config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 347, in image_to_string
    }[output_type]()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 346, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 259, in run_and_get_output
    with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\CRAWLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\4\\tess_pwzjqnpq.txt'
['C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe', 'C:\\Users\\CRAWLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\4\\tess_pwzjqnpq.PNG', 'C:\\Users\\CRAWLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\4\\tess_pwzjqnpq', '-l', 'eng', '--psm', '10', '--oem', '3', '-c', 'tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789', 'txt']
```

Hi all, I am facing this problem in my Windows Server.
the error is  = **pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (3221225477, '')***

I tried this solution [raise “pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (3221225477, '')”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439138/raise-pytesseract-pytesseract-tesseracterror-3221225477)

but it did not work.

the last line of the error is the cmd_args variable of pytesseract.

I wasted hours on this error. I really need help! Thanks..

What I saw for the error was:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\CRAWLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\4\\tess_pwzjqnpq.txt'
```

before this error occurred, a file created as "tess_pwzjqnpq" but there were no .txt at the end of the name of the file. and after the error, it immediately deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is installing an older tesseract version that is not an alpha version with admin rights.